# The page where output data from mySQL is blank

Tags: mysql, node.js, reactjs

I am implementing a ReactJS, NodeJS and MySQL application. when I try to display the Data table that i input, it gives this error message and displays a black page. asking for some help...

The system worked previously but suddenly started not to work. thought it was because I added a new part of fetching user email.so I tried without it but still not working...

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

const ViewBusescard = () => {
  const [busData, setBusData] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    axios.get("http://localhost:5000/busDetails")
      .then(res => {
        setBusData(res.data);
        console.log(busData);
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="card shadow mb-4">
      <div className="card-header py-3">
        <h6 className="m-0 font-weight-bold text-primary">Registered Buses</h6>
      </div>
      <div className="card-body">
        <div className="table-responsive">
          <table className="table table-bordered" id="dataTable" width="100%" cellspacing="0">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th>Bus No</th>
                <th>Bus Type</th>
                <th>Num of Seats</th>
                <th>License Renew Date</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              {busData.map(bus => (
                <tr key={bus.Bus_No}>
                  <td>{bus.Bus_No}</td>
                  <td>{bus.Bus_type}</td>
                  <td>{bus.No_ofSeats}</td>
                  <td>{bus.Bus_License_expireDate}</td>
                </tr>
              ))}
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default ViewBusescard;
```

`RESULT`
DevTools failed to load source map: Could not load content for chrome-extension://fheoggkfdfchfphceeifdbepaooicaho/sourceMap/chrome/scripts/iframe_form_check.js.map: System error: net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT

Comment: This seem like some Chrome extension issue and not React? The code provided is syntactically correct